# Convert NSString to NSMutable String

Tags: objective-c

I am using the NSString in my program i need to convert this into NSMutable string.
i need some syntax for this conversion.
I am able to convert NSArray to NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSMutableString *mutableString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:yourString];
```

Here you go.

Comment: just a question: doesn't `stringWithString` give a NSString as result? Or doesn't that matter?

Comment: @Jodocus: It doesn't matter. If you call the stringWithString from the NSMutableString class it will return as a NSMutableString and thus give you the wanted results.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative

```
NSMutableString *mutableString = [yourString mutableCopy];
```

This gives you a string you own.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `NSMutableString.setString`. Create a new `NSMutableString`, call `setString:yourCurrentNSString`.